How can I install Automation Anywhere bot agent?
I logged into my account in Automation Anywhere Community Edition webpage and I was trying to connect my local device.

I needed to install the bot agent to connect and .exe file download started automatically. But I can't use .exe file for Kubuntu. How do I install Automation Anywhere bot agent?

To the close voters: I used Kubuntu. It is an official Ubuntu flavour.

As per documentation of Automation Anywhere, bot agent cannot be installed on Linux systems.

The Bot Agent cannot be installed on Linux systems. You cannot register a device that is running on a Linux system. However, you can use a registered device running on a Windows system to access a Control Room that is installed on a Linux system.


